# Pthread producer/consumer homework problem. Can you tell me why my program isn't writing all the words from the file to output?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pthreads, producer-consumer

I have to write a C program for my Operating Systems class. This is a producer/consumer problem problem for Linux. The problem description states that the mainline code opens a file descriptor for the input file, and creates three pthreads. Each pthread is to execute a different function.

The file descriptor is passed to the first pthread, which reads lines from the input file, line by line into a a buffer shared with the second pthread. The buffer size is 10.

The second pthread reads lines from the shared buffer, and splits each line into a set of words. Each word is then read into a second buffer shared with the third pthread. The second buffer size is 20.

The third pthread reads words from the second buffer, counts the number of words read, and writes each word to standard output.

For some reason, my algorithm fails to write all the words from the file to standard output. Sometimes I get a segmentation fault, other times it prints only some of the words to output then exits, and at other times the program is left hanging. I can't figure out where the problem lies.

My code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// first shared buffer
char line_buffer[10][200];
int in1 = 0;
int out1 = 0;

// second shared buffer
char word_buffer[20][50];
int in2 = 0;
int out2 = 0;


// function for first pthread
void * one(void *arg) {
  int file = *((int *)arg);
  char next_char_buffer[1];
  int n;
  int i;

  while ((n=read(file, next_char_buffer,1)) > 0) {
    while ((in1 + 1) % 10 == out1) {
      // first buffer full
      sched_yield();
    }
    
    if (next_char_buffer[0] == '\n') { // end of line
      line_buffer[in1][i] = '\0'; // null terminate string
      in1 = ++in1 % 10;
      i = 0;
    }
    else {
      // read char to buffer      
      line_buffer[in1][i++] = next_char_buffer[0];
    }
  }

  while ((in1 + 1) % 10 == out1) {
    // first buffer full    
    sched_yield();
  }
  line_buffer[in1][0] = '\0'; // EOF signal for second thread
  in1 = ++in1 % 10;

  printf("Exit 1 \n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}


// function for second pthread
void * two(void *arg) {
  int i;
  
  // left and right indexes of a word in the line
  int l;
  int r;

  int lines = 0; // number of lines read

  while (lines == 0 || line_buffer[out1][0] != '\0') {
    while (in1 == out1) {
      // first buffer empty      
      sched_yield();
    }

    l = 0;
    r = 0;

    while (line_buffer[out1][r] != '\0') {
      if (line_buffer[out1][r] == ' ') {
        while ((in2 + 1) % 20 == out2) {
          // second buffer full
          sched_yield();
        }
        while (l < r) {
          // write char to second buffer
          word_buffer[in2][i++] = line_buffer[out1][l++];
        }
        word_buffer[in2][i] = '\0'; // null terminate string
        in2 = ++in2 % 20;
        i = 0;
        l++;
        r++;
      }
      else {
        r++;
      }
    }
    out1 = ++out1 % 10;
    lines++;  
  }
  
  while ((in2 + 1) % 20 == out2) {
    // second buffer full
    sched_yield();
  }
  word_buffer[in2][0] = '\0'; // signal end of input
  in2 = ++in2 % 20;

  printf("Exit 2\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}



// function for third pthread
void * three(void *arg) {
  int i = 0;
  int words = 0; // word count
  
  while(words == 0 || word_buffer[out2][0] != '\0') {
    while (in2 == out2) {
      // second buffer empty
      sched_yield();
    }
    printf("%s \n\n", word_buffer[out2]);
    words++;
    out2 = ++out2 % 20;
    i++;
  }
  printf("Word count: %d \n",words);
  printf("Exit 3\n");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}







int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Check for 2 arguments or raise error
  if (argc != 2){
    write(STDERR_FILENO,"Error 1\n",8);
    exit(-1);
    return -1;
  }

  // file descriptor
  int file;
  if ((file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0)) == -1) {
    printf("Can't open file");
    exit(-1);
    return -1;
  }

  // create pthreads
  pthread_t tid_1, tid_2, tid_3;
  pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, one, &file);
  pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, two, NULL);
  pthread_create(&tid_3, NULL, three, NULL);

  // join pthreads
  pthread_join(tid_1,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid_2,NULL);
  pthread_join(tid_3,NULL);  


  // close the file
  printf("Exit main");
  exit(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you are using spin locks. That is, you are constantly just checking a shared variable in a loop. Are you sure the assignment allows that? I would suspect that a major learning objective would be to get you to use OS synchronisation primitives such as mutexes and semaphores.

Comment: Error 1: `while (n=read(file, next_char_buffer,1) > 0)` needs to be `while ((n=read(file, next_char_buffer,1)) > 0)`. Note the difference in brackets. `>` has higher precedence than `=`. So your original code is actually assigning the `read(file, next_char_buffer,1) > 0` (a boolean result) into `n`.

Comment: By spin locks you're referring the the calls the sched_wait? Because using sched_wait is what the professor wants us to use.

Comment: Using ```((n=read(file, next_char_buffer,1)) > 0)``` gives me the same issue.

Comment: `sched_yield()` on Linux is only really defined when using certain non-default schedulers... It may or may not do anything the way you're using it. Can't depend on it. If your professor is telling you to use it for coordinating the execution of threads you're either missing setting up the scheduler or he doesn't know as much as he thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Your program accesses variables (e.g. `in1`, `in2`, etc.) from multiple threads *without any synchronization*.

That's a data race, which is undefined behavior, and makes the result of your program undefined -- it could do anything.

The next bug is that `i` in `one()` and `two()` may be used uninitialized -- it's best to initialize variables when you declare them.

The next bug is that `two()` only emits the word when it finds a space, thus eating last word on every line.

With above bugs fixed, the program works, but still exhibits the data race.
You would need to use `_Atomic` type to avoid that (if you don't want to use a regular mutex that is).

P.S. As others have commented, this use of `sched_yield` is non-standard, and also extremely inefficient (wastes a lot of CPU). A much better approach is to use condition variables here.

Comment: Can you show me how to properly implement the _Atomic type in this case? I'm pretty lost here, it seems like what I need to do.

Comment: @MarkAllan You should fix the other two problems first. That will get you a working (at least on x86) program.